# search my list help with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a

```
    list<fruitObj>


    Fruit
    FruitName, FruitColor
    banana, yellow
    orange, orange
    cherry, red

    List<FruitObj> test = new List<FruitObj>();
```

Is there an inline way of searching the list for starts with BAN and just return true if it does contain the string?

Comment: Can you please publish the source code of the FruitObj class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool hasBAN = test.Any( x => x.FruitName.StartsWith("BAN"));
```

Note that this is case sensitive, to match "banana" you could do:

```
bool hasBAN = test.Any( x => x.FruitName.StartsWith("BAN", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 3):

This does **case insensitive**:

```
 bool hasAnyBAN = test.Any(x=>x.StartsWith("BAN", StringCoparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool startsWithBan = test.Any(f => 
    f.Name.StartsWith("ban", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Assuming Name is a property that contains the fruit name.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of assumptions here...

IF a FruitObj has a .Name property that can be one of the names you listed, you could do this:

```
list.Any(f => f.Name.StartsWith("BAN"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test.Where(fo => fo.FruitName.ToUpper().StartsWith("BAN"));

if (test.Count(fo => fo.FruitName.ToUpper().StartsWith("BAN")) > 0) 
{
    //... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasBAN = test.Any(fruit => fruit.FruitName.ToUpper().StartsWith("BAN"));
```